# How can I view a Send Definition after creating it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

After creating a SendDefinition using the ExactTarget API,

```
CreateResult[] cResults = etClient.Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] { esd }, out cRequestID, out cStatus);
```

How can I have a look at the SendDefinition on the ExactTarget web dashboard without calling `.Perform`?  I just want to see/double-check to make sure it's going to the right place and everything looks OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Marketing Cloud - go to the **Email** application.

Once you are in the **Email** application, hover over the **Interactions** tab.  In this tab, select **User-Initiated Emails** for standard Email Send Definition, or select **Triggered Emails** for Triggered Send Definition types.

This will bring up a list of your send definitions. Find and click on the definition name, and you will see a page similar to below with your details:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Found them, I never related 'user initiated emails' with 'send definitions'.